# Lineage not created when scanning Delta table in Azure Purview

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-purview

A delta table is created from data bricks under the Azure blob storage container by providing its mount path. It is scanned in Azure purview using the Azure blob storage asset, the Lineage is not generated.
It would be helpful if any suggestion to achieve this is provided.

Or provision of direct scan from Databricks delta table is also appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Purview do not support Lineage from Azure Blob or Data Bricks yet.

Comment: Ok, do we have an approximate date when this can be achieved. It means a lot to us if this is in the MSFT roadmap. Thanks